# HCM (High Contrast Mode) white vs black detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, contrast

Does anyone know a jquery or javascript method or methods for testing hcm; whether it's black or white? I have an image on my site that shows up under normal circumstances, and an image that shows up under black, but need to detect if HCM is set to white.

Comment: there are CSS color names that reflect system color settings. these are the ones like buttonface, buttontext, threedshadow, tooltip, etc. these might not fully work on all OS/Browser combos, so test your targets. you can set the named color and then read the current color value to get an RGB for each one.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria-practices/#accessiblewidget Scroll down to 2.12 Compensate for Background Images when in High Contrast Mode